# How do servers allow right-click events?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a minigame on my Spigot server and can't seem to find out how to make right-click events like servers do. For example, I want to be able to receive speed effects after right-clicking sugar, but I currently have repeating command blocks that detect if a player meets "SelectedItem"requirements.

Some use teleporting armor stands to trigger when they right-click them, but that seems like a hassle.
Others use carrots on a stick and retexture it to detect its use, but I don't want custom resource packs on my server.

Do servers use these methods to detect right-clicks? There must be another way.

Comment: @Joachim This question is asking how modded servers implement right click detection, which is presumably different from the hacky methods suggested in that question. (I don't disagree this should be closed, but the correct close reason is "Off Topic as Game Development", not "duplicate")

Comment: @pppery But the server-side part seems to unnecessarily complicate the goal of the question (and that questions have hacky answers shouldn't influence VTCing as duplicates). As it stands, you're right to close as OTasGD.

Comment: @pppery No, the question is about command blocks. I don't know why the asker mentioned Spigot at all.